# How to add a field to an existing instance with ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, spring, byte-buddy, mongotemplate

I need to throw documents to a MongoDB instance from a Spring application, where I can leverage the MongoTemplate from its data package.

But Spring is taking those instances `id` fields as MongoDB document id, resulting in duplicate ids in the database, thus preventing repeated instances.

This is in a project where:

- I need to throw data to the MongoDB instance for later analysis from the database itself, not from the application (so I don't care if I cant query them back);
- duplicate documents are may exist and are part of the requirements;
- documents are deserializations of web service requests, I could add an `_id` field to the class definition, but a future source generation from the WSDL would discard the field;
- documents are treated this way for testing purposes in this initial phase, they won't be sent to the database after some data has been collected and analyzed

Reading from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44704977/3127111) I see that an `id` field is mandatory for Spring, I need to add a `_id` field somehow.

This is how I'm inserting documents into the collection:

```
public void save(List<MyDocument> docs) {
    mongoTemplate.insert(MyDocument.class).inCollection("docscoll").all(docs);
}
```

I'm totally new to ByteBuddy (I thought this could be the right library for the job, but feel free to suggest another one), by searching here on SO I put together this code:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .redefine(MyDocument.class)
  .defineField("_id", int.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .make()
  .load(MyDocument.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION);
```

But it fails with:

```
Cannot inject already loaded type: class com.MyDocument
```

Comment: This sounds like an awful hack for something that could be done in a much simpler way. I'm not sure I fully understand what you need to do, but: why not define your own class with the required fields, then convert instances of `MyDocument` to that simply by copying fields, and then save the objects of your new class to MongoDB? No bytecode hacking necessary...

Comment: @Jesper Yes, it really is. Apart from the fact that there are lots of fields and the slight risk of adding a bug to the code, I like the idea to add the objects literally unchanged to the store. In fact, it's Spring here forcing me to find a hack, MongoDB would accept the documents as is and automatically add the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work. Most JVMs do not allow to add a field to an already loaded class. So despite the fact that Byte Buddy could adjust the byte code, this would not work even if done correctly once the class is loaded. The correct way would also require a Java agent which can be attached using the Byte Buddy Agent project for example:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .redefine(MyDocument.class)
  .defineField("_id", int.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .make()
  .load(MyDocument.class.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
```

This would however not work due to VM limitations, you can also change method contents.

You could attach a Java agent to add the field prior to application startup where the class is not yet loaded. This can be done using a Java agent and Byte Buddy can implement such an agent easily:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .type(named("<package>.MyDocument"))
  .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
    .defineField("_id", int.class, Visibility.PUBLIC))
  .installOn(<instrumentation>);
```

This way, the field is added before the class is loaded for the first time if you add this code in the `premain` method of your agent.

I do however wonder if this is the correct approach to your problem. I would normally rather use a weak map than byte code instrumentation.

Comment: I see. Yes, this looks like that's not a good solution to the problem.