# Facet + Aggregate Query using ObjectId issue with Spring Data Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am developing **Spring Boot + Spring Data Mongo**. I am really struggling to

```
public Page<EmployeeOut> getData(Pageable pageable) {
    .......
    .......

    MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(criteria);

    GroupOperation groupOp = Aggregation
            .group("firstName", "lastName", "email", "status", "id")
            .addToSet("department").as("department").addToSet("address").as("address");

    ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("firstName", "lastName", "email", "status", "department", "address", "id");

    SkipOperation skipOp = Aggregation.skip((long) pageRequest.getPageNumber() * pageRequest.getPageSize());

    LimitOperation limitOp = Aggregation.limit(pageRequest.getPageSize());

    SortOperation sortOperation = ReferenceUtil.getSortOperation(pageRequest);

    FacetOperation facetOp1 = Aggregation.facet(unwind, matchStage, projectStage, groupOp).as("facet1")
            .and(unwind, matchStage, projectStage, groupOp, sortOperation, skipOp, limitOp).as("facet2");

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(facetOp1);

    AggregationResults<EmployeeOutFacet> EmployeeOutList = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Employee.class, EmployeeOutFacet.class);;

    .....
    return page;
}
```

EmployeeOutFacet.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeOutFacet {
    protected List<EmployeeOut> facet1;
    protected List<EmployeeOut> facet2; 
}
```

EmployeeOut.java

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id","address","departments"})
public class EmployeeOut{

    @JsonProperty(value="id")
    protected EmployeeInner _id;
    protected List<Department> departments;
    protected List<Address> address;
}
```

EmployeeInner.java

```
public class EmployeeInner{
    protected String id;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected Integer email;
    protected String status;
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Document
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String firstName;
    ....
    ....
    ...
}
```

When the Query executes id gives always null, any suggestions?

I've documents like can't paste query due to security.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "email" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
    .........
    .........
    "Addresss" : [ 
        {
            "Address1" : "Address 1",
            .....
            .....
            .....
        }, 
        {
            "Address1" : "Address 11",
            .....
            .....
            .....
        },
        {
            "Address1" : "Address 12",
            .....
            .....
            .....
        },
    ],
    "department" : {
        "departmentCd" : "E",
        ....
        ...
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mapping the id field incorrectly in the both project and group stage.

It should be **_id** not id. Also change the email type to String. Works for me.

```
GroupOperation groupOp = Aggregation
            .group("firstName", "lastName", "email", "status", "_id")
            .addToSet("department").as("department").addToSet("address").as("address");

ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("firstName", "lastName", "email", "status", "department", "address", "_id");

...

AggregationResults<EmployeeOutFacet> EmployeeOutList = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Employee.class), EmployeeOutFacet.class);
```

Comment: I would not post anything I haven’t tested. This works for me as expected. It could be something else that I may be missing. I will look further. What is the spring mongo jar version you use ? Is your entire result set not getting mapped or just the id part in the custom object ? I'm not using any annotations on the class like you have. I would recommended you to try without the annotations.

Comment: Update - works with annotations too. So I dont think json annotation has any impact on the mapping.

Comment: It could be something you are doing in unwind stage which we cant see. For my test, I used project and group for facet stage and it works for me. May you can investigate something in unwind that may be causing issue.

Comment: @PAA He is right, look carefully to your 1st $project, you are using `$ _id` (what you have posted in chat)

Comment: @Valijon Thanks for backing me up on this. - I understand the OP issue now. OP is using `TypedAggregation` (when you specify the input class instead of collection)  in the aggregate second argument. If he were to specify collection name there my suggestion would work. I've added a [comment](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2437?focusedCommentId=188065&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-188065) in the spring mongo project for explanation.

Comment: @user2683814 Completely agree. I never use `TypedAggregation`, its better use raw aggregation (we get collection name with `mongotemplate.getCollectionName(Employee.class)`)

Comment: @Valijon - Could you please suggest code snippet to fix this ?

Comment: You could replace Employee.class with employee collection name in the aggregate call along with replacing id with _id.

Comment: @PAA I've update user2683814 answer. Check it please

Comment: @Valijon - This gives me "firstName", "lastName", "email", "status", "_id" two times, how to restrict it to 1 time only ?